# Please explain the reason for some arguments in this docker run command?

Tags: docker

The line is:
`` docker run --rm -it -v `pwd`:/db some-sqlite test.db ``

referenced here: https://devopsheaven.com/sqlite/backup/restore/dump/databases/docker/2017/10/10/sqlite-backup-restore-docker.html

It works, but I don't understand the reason for `'pwd':/db` as I can open up the container and play around

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's mounting your current directory in the host (`pwd`) in the `/db` directory in the container, so that any file added in `/db/*` will also be stored in your current directory in the host.